# AWS DMS Oracle Migrate Multiple Schemas in One Task

Tags: oracle, aws-dms

I've been working on migrating an Oracle database to AWS using DMS.

Initially, I set up a basic migration task, where the source and target connections had admin access.

When I ran the task, it brought the source data over from all schemas but put it all in the admin schema on the target.

I then manually created the schemas and re-ran the full-sync task, limiting it to only some schemas of interest. I was hoping that if the schemas were pre-created, it wouldn't default to the admin schema.

Once again, the data was copied over ok, but all ended up in the admin schema.

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. Do I need to create a DMS task for each schema and set the target to the specific schema? The tool looks to me like it's built to handle multiple schemas. It can certainly pull multiple source schemas at the same time. Am I just missing a setting in the migration task? Is it because I didn't have the schemas created on the target before the first task ran and now it remembers the previous mapping?